# Thread error in IBAction while overriding prepareForSegue function

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm getting a thread error `Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1` in my `IBAction` function. The code runs without error, but when I click the button on the simulator, the simulator crashes and produces the breakpoint error. The affected code is:

```
@IBAction override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if testoEsercizio.text == "Per iniziare premi la tv" {
        var viewController : SecondoSchermo = segue.destinationViewController as SecondoSchermo
        viewController.stringaponte = "SI buono"
    } else {
        var viewController : SecondoSchermo = segue.destinationViewController as SecondoSchermo
        viewController.stringaponte = "NON buono"
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Open the breakpoint editor in Xcode with `⌘ + 7`.  From there you can see the breakpoints that are on (as indicated by dark blue) or off (with light blue).  I highly suspect that you have a breakpoint set in your method.

The term `Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1` is the debugger's internal name for the breakpoint (I Assume you're reading this from the green bar of text?).  It doesn't necessarily mean it is a 
threading error, it's just telling you where it stopped.

You can press `^ + ⌘ + Y` to Continue, or go to the Debug Menu and select other options. `⇧ + ⌘ + Y` will bring up the Debug area and a bar of buttons which correlate to the Debug Menu's actions.

HTH

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it means indeed that you set a breakpoint in your code. If you did so by mistake, press CMD+7 to select all breakpoints in Xcode. In the breakpoint navigator on the left you can now select and delete your breakpoints with backspace

Answer (score 2):

Have you accidentally added a breakpoint to your code? If so, program will run up until that point and then stop.

Check whether there are any blue arrows linked to some part of your program which mark a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the (dark blue) sign, and the green message will go away. And the next part of your code will be accessible from simulation or else.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you should follow this instructions.

1- Go to Product in the toolbar.

2- Then go to Scheme.

3- And go to Edit scheme.

4- Then click on Run(Debug).

5- in Run(Debug) there is Arguments Passed On launch just click on + then put this value on it (-v)

6- Close.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem, the easiest way to solve this issue is to click on the debug option in the tool menu at the top of the screen and you will then you find the option "deactivate breakpoints".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the two steps to solve this:

Remove break point, by going to `DEBUG` and `DEACTIVATE ALL BREAK POINT`

Then, go to `Main.Storyboard`, right click on the area highlighted in red:

[image: Right Click on Red highlighted area]

Check that the yellow sign is present or not. If present then remove this. Code will run successfully. App will not crash.

[image: No Crash]