# xcode 5 thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 - Struggling

Tags: xcode, multithreading, breakpoints, sigabrt

I have been struggling with this error for several days now:

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

I know that there are many answers online, but none of them have worked for me. From making sure the Global Breakpoint button was off to adding an Exception Breakpoint, I am having no luck. I am new to Xcode and am not good at all with coding. Also I have had the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, but after fiddling with it for a while it went away... and was replaced by this. PLEASE HELP ME!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we don't know what you've tried, we don't know how to help you. For example, have you started with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750595/error-thread-1-breakpoint-1-1

Comment: Thank you Rob, I had not seen that posting before, but I don't have any breakpoints in my project. I have made a new project to try to duplicate the old one without errors but my attempts have been futile. I now have a signal SIGABRT error on one and a breakpoint 1.1 on the other. Is SIGABRT easier to solve?. I have tried just about everything that popped up on the first 3 pages of my google searches for both errors. Including adding exception breakpoints, to changing the code (which I don't really understand, I was following a tutorial). Anything else I can do?

Comment: Also, could using Static Cells in my table view be affecting the error? The error crashes the simulator when I try to click on the cell that should bring me to the next screen. Thanks Again @RobNapier

Comment: If you're following tutorials, I would start again, and work through the tutorial step by step. The goal is learning the system first. SIGABRT is a generic message. It doesn't tell us anything useful. You likely have a bug in the code, but If you're just starting, I'd focus first on just trying to follow your lessons closely.

Comment: Thanks Rob, both of the tutorials that I have found and tried have had errors that other people have had and I found a fix for one, which I am using now, but even after the fix I still get one error - the SIGABRT one