# Changing the image in UIImageView, other XCode issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I'm really new to XCode(swift), and I'm trying to make a UIImageView randomly show one of three images, but when I switch to the second viewController in the simulator, nothing happens and XCode highlights the end of the ViewDidLoad function saying Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1.

If there's a better or more reliable way to get UIImageView to switch images, I would definitely like to know.

My current code:

```
import UIKit

let imageInitialIdentity = arc4random_uniform(3)

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if(imageInitialIdentity == 0){
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named: "0ps.pngs")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
        }
        if(imageInitialIdentity == 1){
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named: "250ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
        }
        if(imageInitialIdentity == 2){
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named: "500ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }


    @IBOutlet weak var imageGuess: UIImageView!

    var imageIdentity = imageInitialIdentity
    var score = 0
    let imageZero = UIImage.init(named: "0ps")
    let image250 = UIImage.init(named: "250ps")
    let image500 = UIImage.init(named: "500ps")





    @IBAction func guessZero(sender: UIButton) {

        //if zero matches the picture 0, add a point
        if imageIdentity == 0{
            score++
        }
        else{
            //print incorrect, corect answer is 0
        }

            //randomizes another picture
            let rand1 = arc4random_uniform(3)
            if rand1 == 0 {
                imageGuess.image = UIImage(named: "0ps.png")
                imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
                imageIdentity = 0
            }
            else if rand1 == 1{
                imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"250ps.png")
                imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
                imageIdentity = 1
            }
            else if rand1 == 2{
                imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"500ps.png")
                imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
                imageIdentity = 2
            }

    }

    @IBAction func guess250(sender: UIButton) {
        // if 150 matches the picture of 250, return true
        //randomizes another picture
        //adds one to score?
        if imageIdentity == 1{
            score++
        }


        let rand2 = arc4random_uniform(3)
        if rand2 == 0 {
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"0ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 0
        }
        else if rand2 == 1{
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"250ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 1

        }
        else if rand2 == 2{
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"500ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 2
        }
    }

    @IBAction func guess500(sender: UIButton) {
        //if 500 matches the picture of 500, return true
        //randomizes another picture
        if imageIdentity == 2{
            score++
        }


        let rand3 = arc4random_uniform(3)
        if rand3 == 0 {
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"0ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 0
        }
        else if rand3 == 1{
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"250ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 1

        }
        else if rand3 == 2{
            imageGuess.image = UIImage(named:"500ps.png")
            imageGuess.frame = CGRect(x: 51, y: 47, width: 500, height: 340)
            imageIdentity = 2
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a breakpoint set. Disable or delete the breakpoint.

Comment: You can follow the instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750595/error-thread-1-breakpoint-1-1 for how to turn breakpoints off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set a breakpoint. Usually caused by accident when clicking to view errors. If you click the blue arrow like button it will deactivate the break point:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the code is running from one ViewController to this SecondViewController, and program breaks at viewDidLoad, you might want to check how does the code finish up with its previous class and what makes it run SecondViewController class. Once you are done checking that, you might want to move your random methods out of viewDidLoad to figure out what exactly is causing the crash. something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    randomMethod()
}
func randomMethod() // put a break point here if viewDidLoad passes
{
     if(imageInitialIdentity == 0){
     ..... your code ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "If there's a better or more reliable way to get UIImageView to switch images".

Short answer, no, that's the way it's done.
One thing you should watch out is that you have to set the image on the main thread to see change. The viewDidLoad method is certainly running on the main thread so no worries here.
If you decide to update the imageview's image at a later time, you can use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) to properly update your UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // update your UI here
});
```

If you need to quickly switch between two images in an imageview, you can use the highlightedImage property.
You set this property same as you did for the image property (with a different image of course).
Then, all you need to do is set the highlighted property to YES or NO.

```
UIImageView *iv = [UIImageView new];
UIImage *firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_image.png"];
iv.image = firstImage;
iv.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second_image.png"];
// Call below code whenever you want to switch the image, by setting the boolean.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    iv.highlighted = YES;
});
```

One thing that I would recommend is using the image size property for the imageview's frame.

```
iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, firstImage.size.width, firstImage.size.height);
```