# NSDictionary has value of none

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I want the user to add Friends. However whenever I click on **addFriend** button I get a breakpoint with an `thread 1`. There is no further error information rather than `11db`. 
I have found out by now that the `NSDictionary` of "otherUser" has the value of none. Thats the reason everything is not working. However I have no clue why that is. Out of the same `NSDictionary` , I get the username and the profile Pic. Why is it nil then?

```
var otherUser: NSDictionary?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
databaseRef.child("user").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let uid = self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String
        self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "uid")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
@IBAction func addFriend(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.befreunden.titleLabel?.text == "Als Freund hinzufügen" {

    let friendRef = "befreundet/\(self.loggedinUSerData?["uid"] as! String)/\(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String)"

    let BefreundenData = ["username":self.otherUser?["username"] as? String,
                              "ProfilePic":self.otherUser?["urltoImage"] as! String!]


    let childUpdats = [friendRef:BefreundenData]

        databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdats)

        }else {

            FreundeAnzahl = self.otherUser?["AnzahlFreunde"] as! Int + 1

        }
}
```

**Edit:**

I've just found out, that the NSDictionary of otherUser has all the values needed inside the viewdidLoad. But as soon as I call the uid of the otherUser in the addFriend function it gives back a value of nil.
Why is it happening?

Comment: in which line your code stopped ?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750595/error-thread-1-breakpoint-1-1

Comment: it stops in let FriendRef.

Comment: It stops because you are force unwrapping an optional that is nil. Without seeing the dictionary there is no possible way to answer this question more than to tell you not to EVER force unwrap optionals. All it does is lead to pain and bugs. (Like this one).

Comment: but why is that optional nil? As I said in the viewdidload it has an optional value which i can force to unwrap without any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by simple giving the uid of the otheruser NSDictionary to a new variable which I created in the viewdidLoad. 
This way I do not face any issues regarding unwrapping optionals later on.