# iOS why tableview always stop in breakpoint?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I create a `TableView` via `StoryBoard`. I connect all the element to a `UITableViewCell` class call `PostTableCell`. I already set `identifier` for the `tableCell`  in `StoryBoard`. My code is as below:

```
class PopViewController: UIViewController ,IndicatorInfoProvider ,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var popTableView: UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        popTableView.dataSource = self
        popTableView.delegate = self

        fetchInitialPost()
    }


    func fetchInitialPost(){
        Alamofire.request(MyURL, method: .get).responseJSON{
            response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let result):

                let json = JSON(result)
                guard let feedArr = json["feed"].array else{
                    return
                }

                for post in feedArr {
                    if let post = post.dictionary,let feed = Post.init(dict: post){
                        self.posts.append(feed)
                    }
                }

                self.popTableView.reloadData()

                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabScripController : PagerTabStripViewController ) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return IndicatorInfo (title : "Pop")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostTableCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableCell
        cell.posts = self.posts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

I think I do all I should do in order to make it work already. But when I run the project I gives me this error, but I don't have any error in console. The app is just blank and this error below pops out.

[image]

So what cause this problem? And how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure your outlet is properly connected.

Comment: It's not an error. You have set a [breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

Comment: Is the table view connected in Interface Builder? By the way, connecting `datasource` and `delegate` also in IB is more convenient than in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750595/error-thread-1-breakpoint-1-1)

Comment: ya the tableView already connected in code.

Comment: You cannot connect an outlet *in code*

Comment: @FelixSFD I already see this question before I ask..but seems like not the same

Comment: @vadian then what should I do??

Comment: Connect the outlet in **Interface Builder**. Control-drag from the view controller icon to the table view and choose `popTableView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when there is a problem when loading the Storyboard.

I think (this has happend to me multiple times) you maybe have **User Defined Runtime Attributes** on `popTableView` in your Storyboard. If there are any that can not be set, because `popTableView` does not have the respective property, the debugger will show the behavior that you are seeing.

You can check if there are any **User Defined Runtime Attributes** by selecting the table view in Interface Builder an checking the **Identity Inspector**.

[image]

Try deleting any attributes that might cause problems.

Alternatively you forgot to connect the `@IBOutlet` in your Storyboard. You can check how to do that in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html).

Comment: in User Defined Runtime Attributes dont have anything...so what I should do ya??

Comment: If User Defined Runtime Attributes are not the problem, then you forgot to connect the `@IBOutlet`. See the bottom of my response.

Comment: I already connect the IBOutlet as well..but still the same problem